# Capybara can't find element if I use CanCan load_and_authorize_resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I'm new to Cucumber and I'm writing my first test. I'm having a problem when I try to include CanCan load_and_authorize_resource function inside my UsersController. If I comment, remove that line everything runs.

My Ability:

```
if user.nil?
    cannot :manage, :all
elsif user.have_the_role? :user
    can :read, User
    # this allowes me to update just my profile
    can :update, User, :id => user.id
elsif user.have_the_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
end
```

My Feature:

```
Scenario: New User
  Given I login with my google_apps account
  When I am redirected to create my profile
  And I fill in "First Name" with "Ricardo"
  And I fill in "Last Name" with "Berdejo"
  And I fill in "National Identifier" with "123456"
  And I select "M" from "Gender"
  And I select "April 26, 1990" as the "Date of Birth" date
  And I fill in "Cellphone Number" with "000000000"
  And I fill in "Personal Email" with "personal@email.com"
  And I fill in "Home Address" with "some direction"
  And I fill in "Title" with "Developer"
  And I fill in "Healthcare Company" with "EPS"
  And I fill in "Emergency Contact Name" with "Mom"
  And I fill in "Emergency Contact Phone" with "9999999"
  And I select "O" from "Blood Group"
  And I select "Positive" from "RH Factor"
  And I press "Save"
  Then I should see "Profile Saved"
```

My step:

```
When(/^I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)"$/) do |field, value|
  fill_in field, :with => value
end
```

Error:

`Unable to find field "First Name" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)`

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `save_and_open_page` before your `fill_in` line to see the error page.

Comment: thanks, I'll use it to debug my code

Comment: well, I think is because CanCan can't access the current_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could solved it. For future readers: Check the role assignment before signing in.
Create a step like

```
Given I am a User
```

or

```
Given I am a Admin
```

and in your steps create a user with a given login/password and role.

```
Given(/^I am an Admin$/) do
  @admin = Fabricate(:admin) do
    email "enter_your_mail_here"
    user_field_1 "Field"
    user_field_2 "Field2"
    role { Fabricate(:role, account_type: "admin") }
  end
end
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I see that the test code is logging in with a Google Apps account. If your test is actually redirecting to Google to log in, you'll need to be sure to use a Capybara driver that can handle redirects to external web sites. The default driver cannot.

See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#selecting-the-driver for details.

Comment: well, actually the login function is running, I used `save_and_open_page` and I could see that CanCan is trying to access the `current_user` but It's always nil.